# Sumário instead of Conteúdo for toc?

Tags: table-of-contents, babel, languages

In a Portuguese text I am writing I am using `\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}`, and get *Conteúdo* as the heading for the table of contents. But I get the advise that it is better to use Sumário as the heading.

May I obtain *Sumário*?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since you're using the `babel` package with the the `portuguese` language option, you may achieve your formatting objective by issuing the instruction

```
\addto\extrasportuguese{\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Sumário}}
```

after `\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}` in the preamble.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
\addto\extrasportuguese{\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Sumário}}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{Olá Mundo}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 17):

The “modern” way to do this with `babel` is with `\setlocalecaption`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}

\setlocalecaption{portuguese}{contents}{Sumário}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{Olá Mundo}
\end{document}
```

[image]